# Filtrar email por assunto com script PHP

Tags: php, email

Bem, tenho um script que faz a leitura do e-mail, porém tenho que passar como parâmetro o numero sequencial da mensagem que quero abrir.

Gostaria de abrir as mensagens com determinado Subject e executar operações com as mesmas.

tentei adaptar o script para ler conforme eu quero, mas ele me retorna erro.

```
    $login = 'email';
    $senha = 'senha';

    $str_conexao = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}';
    if (!extension_loaded('imap')) {
        die('Modulo PHP/IMAP nao foi carregado');
     }

     // Abrindo conexao
    $mailbox = imap_open($str_conexao, $login, $senha);
    if (!$mailbox) {
       die('Erro ao conectar: '.imap_last_error());
     } 
    $check = imap_check($mailbox);

    // Ultima mensagem
    echo "Data ".$check->Date."<br>";

    // Tipo de conexao
    echo "Conexão ".$check->Driver."<br>";

    // Mailbox
    echo "Caixa de email ".$check->Mailbox."<br>";

    // Numero de mensagens total
    echo "Mensagens total ".$check->Nmsgs."<br>";

   //ultima mensagem recebida
   $msg = $check->Nmsgs;

   $i=1;
while ( $i < $msg ) {

$header = imap_header($mailbox, $i);

$subject_hold = $header->Subject;
if($subject_hold == "TESTE"){
    echo "Resultado encontrado: <br>";
    /*
    // Data
    echo $header->Date;
    // Endereco do destinatario
    echo $header->toaddress;
    // Endereco do remetente
    echo $header->fromaddress;
    */
    // Assunto da mensagem
    echo $header->Subject."<br>";
    }
  $i++;
}
```

Porém ele me retorna esse erro:

[image: Imagem de erro exibida no navegador pelo PHP]

Comment: A função que está a procura é [imap_search](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imap-search.php)

Comment: Eu consegui abrir os e-mail's da forma que descrevi, porém ainda recebo esses valores de erro (Como na imagem).

Comment: A minha sugestão era no sentido de não ter de fazer o processamento manualmente uma vez que o `imap_search` já trás um array de emails que tenham um determinado critério podendo este ser por titulo, tamanho, data, etc. Em relação ao erro parece me que pelo menos um dos emails não ficou com o `Subject` construído. Está a conseguir ler algum email pelo menos, ou dá erro em todos?

Comment: Consigo abrir todos, o erro era porque alguns emails não possuíam o Subject. Enfim, consegui resolver o problema, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta usar [imap_fetch_overview()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php)

eu penso que desta maneira é mais fácil do que usar imap_header, exemplo:

```
// usei o ciclo for porque é mais conveniente nesta situação
// tem cuidado com $i = 1, verifica se começa no indice 0
for ($i = 1; $i < $check->Nmsgs; $i++) { 

    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($mailbox, $i, 0);

    if($overview[0]->subject == "TESTE")
    {
        // teu codigo
    }

}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o meu problema, muito obrigado!